# How do I read all the routeUp objects?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read routeUp node`s all the objects.How can I read it?

This is the database :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELYqF.png)

Comment: Have solved the issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo no.. Have you any idea?

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer now.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the object within your `routeUp` node, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference routeRef = rootRef.child("route");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.child("routeUp").getChildren()) {
                String haltName = ds.child("haltName").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, haltName);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
routeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
Kaduwela
//an so on
```